# How to specify Ensures for out parameter?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I have a method with an `out` parameter and I want to specify using `Contract.Ensures()` that when the method returns, the parameter will not be `null`.

Basically, this:

```
void M(out object o)
{
    Contract.Ensures(o != null);

    o = new object();
}
```

This does not compile, because it looks like the parameter will be read before it's assigned:

> error CS0269: Use of unassigned out parameter 'o'

I thought I could fix this by switching the lines around, but that does not work either:

> warning CC1005: CodeContracts: Malformed contract. Found Ensures after assignment in method 'M(System.Object@)'.

Is there some way to do this?

I don't want to switch the method to `ref`. I can't return the value instead of using `out`, because the actual method where I encountered this already has a return value: `bool TryGetValue(TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, out TValue value)`.

Comment: Which c# version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Contract.ValueAtReturn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412864%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is available specifically to avoid the C# compiler's error here.

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.ValueAtReturn(out o) != null);
```