# How to specify Requires for out parameter?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

Related to this question: [How to specify Ensures for out parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153285/how-to-specify-ensures-for-out-parameter)

How can I do this for the `Ensures.Requires()`-method?

Comment: You don't, because that would be meaningless. An `out` parameter isn't set by the caller, so you can't attach any preconditions to it (nor do you have to).

Comment: In my case, the caller has set the parameter. The method changes the value.
Is it a better way, to use two parameters?

Comment: If the caller has to set the parameter is is NOT really an `out` parameter. It is a `ref` parameter. Do not abuse `out` parameters in this way (even though you are allowed to) - it will likely confuse people calling the method.

Comment: Thank you, its my bad, I used the variable twice. As normal parameter and as out-parameter. I need definitely more coffee. :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: don't worry, it isn't *possible* to abuse them that way. Any attempt to access an `out` parameter before it's assigned in the method itself gives an "use of uninitialized out-parameter" compiler error. You can, of course, pass the same variable as both an `out` and a non-`out` parameter, but that's the caller's choice, and has predictable semantics. Any preconditions would only be defined on to the regular parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I used the `out`-keyword incorrectly.
As [Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson) said, I have to use `ref`-parameter.

So I have no more problems with `Contract.Requires()`.